# Navegar en un ArrayList con un ListIterator en JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, iteradores

Tengo el siguiente método:

```
/**
 * Este método sirve para pasarle un ArrayList y mostrarlo en otro JFrame.<br>
 * Tiene dos botones bAnterior y bSiguiente que navega entre los valores del ArrayList.<br>
 * Navegamos a través de una ListIterator ya que se puede previous y next.
 * @param listaValores ArrayList con los valores guardados.
 * @param titulo String para cambiar el título de la ventana de mostrar datos.
 */
private void mostrarDatos (ArrayList<String> listaValores, String titulo){
    MostrarDatos datosFrame = new MostrarDatos();
    datosFrame.lTitulo.setText(titulo);
    datosFrame.setVisible(true);
    
    ListIterator<String> lit = listaValores.listIterator();
    datosFrame.taMostrarDatos.setText(lit.next().toString());
    
    datosFrame.bAnterior.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            if (lit.hasPrevious()){
                //datosFrame.taMostrarDatos.setText(VehiculosDAO.recuperarTodosVehiculos().get(2));
                //lit.previous();
                datosFrame.taMostrarDatos.setText(lit.previous().toString());
            }
        }
    });
    
    datosFrame.bSiguiente.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            if (lit.hasNext()){
                //datosFrame.taMostrarDatos.setText(VehiculosDAO.recuperarTodosVehiculos().get(2));
                //lit.next();
                datosFrame.taMostrarDatos.setText(lit.next().toString());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Funciona bien, o al menos eso creo. Solo tengo un fallo que no se como arreglar.

Cuando quiero cambiar de un registro next a otro previous o viceversa, tengo que pulsar dos veces sobre el botón para que se muestre el resultado correcto.
Cuando voy pulsando el botón bSiguiente, el iterator se posiciona sobre el siguiente registro, entonces, al pulsar el botón bAnterior para retroceder, este me posiciona el iterador en el registro anterior (QUÉ RESULTA SER EL MISMO QUE SE ESTÁ MOSTRANDO) y por eso tengo que dar dos veces del botón cada vez que quiero cambiar de sentido.

¿Cómo puedo arreglar ese fallo?

Comment: No uses un iterador, usa el spliterador, esta hecho para ir en ambos sentidos

Comment: ListIterator también

Answer (score 0):

Yo personalmente no usaría un listIterator y haría lo siguiente:

```
int i = 0;
datosFrame.taMostrarDatos.setText(listaValores.get(i).toString());

datosFrame.bAnterior.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            if (i-1 >= 0){
                i -= 1;
                datosFrame.taMostrarDatos.setText(listaValores.get(i).toString());
            }
        }
});

datosFrame.bSiguiente.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            if (i+1 < listaValores.lenght()){
               i += 1;
               datosFrame.taMostrarDatos.setText(listaValores.get(i).toString());
            }
        }
});
```